# הכל בידי שמים אף יראת שמים? Is this just the Mei HaShiloach's Chiddush?

Tags: chasidut-hasidism, yirat-shamaim

The [Mei HaShiloach](https://www.sefaria.org/Mei_HaShiloach%2C_Volume_I%2C_Genesis%2C_Vayera.3?lang=bi&with=Tanakh&lang2=en) writes regarding [Sarah Eimeinu's denial of her Laughter](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.18.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

(*Partial Quote; see in full for context*)

> עומק הענין בזה, כי מה דאיתא בגמ' (ברכות ל"ג:) הכל בידי שמים חוץ מיראת שמים הוא רק לפי גבול תפיסת שכל האדם, אבל באמת הכל בידי שמים ואף יראת שמים ורק בעוה"ז הסתיר הש"י דרכו.

> *The (subject) matter is very deep with this (verse), for when the Gemara says ([Brachos 33b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.33b.23?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) "Everything is in the hands of heaven except for the fear of heaven" is only (true) according to the grasp of the human intellect. **But in truth** "everything is in the hands of heaven"- **even fear of heaven**- and it is only in this world that H-Shem has hidden his ways...*

## My Question

Are there any other sources who talk about this idea, or is this the Mei HaShiloach's chiddush alone?

Comment: רבי חסדאי קרשקש אור השם spinoza

Comment: @kouty ugh. Don't put those two together.

Comment: @TrustMeI'mARabbi Perhaps 'rabbi' you can explain the rest of it. He asks why Sara denied it and he says if she wouldnt have Yitschak would not be able to have children.

Comment: Peri Haarts wrote that איתערותא דלתתא is Min Hashamayim. The extreme opposite is Ralbag and Ibn Daud. Rambam left it as a paradoxe.

Comment: @interested thats not what I'm asking though and what you said is not what he writes.

Comment: @TrustMeI'mARabbi Well then please tell us what he writes, since I dont seem to know.

Comment: @interested but that's not relevant to the question!

Comment: @TrustMeI'mARabbi But one is supposed to teach torah to someone who doesnt know. Isnt that a mitsva.